# Stripe apps in test mode

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-apps

I am trying to test stripe webhooks from connected accounts.

I have 2 accounts:

1. The one that created a stripe app and defined the webhooks
2. The one that installs the app and becomes connected to account 1.

I am expecting that when a payment is created (in test mode) from account 2, it should trigger an event at the webhook defined on account 1, but it doesn't. I think the issue is that when I install the app using the external test link on account 2, the app is available only in live mode.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9uEz.png)

Did anyone encounter this issue?

Comment: Is your Webhook Endpoint on Account 1 set to listen to events on Connected Accounts ? https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks I don't know that this is a live/test mode problem, since Connect webhooks forward events from both modes irrespectively.

Comment: @Lucky2501 Yes, I have defined 2 webhooks, one with type Account and one with type Connect

Comment: are these webhooks in test mode or in live mode?